# How to do simple sql requests on sql developer linux?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle-sqldeveloper

I installed sqldelevoper on linux and try to do some simple sql requests.

When i try to get current date:

```
select date(now());
```

I got an error:

```
"ORA-00936: missing expression."
```

I have no idea what am i doing wrong, i can't normal work with DATE type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be running a MySQL query (or the like) in Oracle. The equivalent would be:

```
select trunc(sysdate) from dual
```

Note that in MySQL, you could phrase this simply as:

```
select current_date
```